# C++, Python, Incompatible Types of Numbers

Tags: c++, python, types, vector, typeerror

I am having difficulty using the vector_indexing_suite in Boost.
In C++ I have defined:

```
  class_<std::vector<double> >("PyVecDouble")
                         .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<double> >());
```

and

```
  class_<std::vector<long> >("PyVecLong")
                         .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<long> >());
```

And in python, I have tried to use these in the following simple program:

```
def NumpyArrayToPyVecDouble(vec):
    n = len(vec)
    p_vec = jp.PyVecDouble()

    for i in xrange(0,n):
        p_vec.append(vec[i])

    return p_vec

def NumpyArrayToPyVecLong(vec):
    n = len(vec)
    p_vec = jp.PyVecLong()

    for i in xrange(0,n):
        p_vec.append(vec[i])

    return p_vec

example_array = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4])
example = NumpyArrayToPyVecDouble(double_array)

dates_array = np.array([01122011, 01062012, 01122012, 01062013])
dates = NumpyArrayToPyVecLong(dates_array)
```

As a result, the program computes the vector example, but returns the following error when it tries to compute the vector dates:

```
TypeError: Attempting to append an invalid type
```

And ideas why?  Are Longs in C++ incompatible with Python?  This also does not work when I replace long everywhere with int.  Help much appreciated!

!UPDATE!
NumpyArrayToPyVecLong works fine when given the input as a python list as opposed to a numpy array.  I've tried making various types of numpy arrays (int16, int32, int64, uint16, etc) but none of them work.  It only works when given a plain python list.  Any ideas why these types are all incompatible with the C++ long?

!UPDATE! the second:
A solution for this is just to use `p_vec.append(vec[i])` but this doesn't actually answer the problem of how numpy arrays and C++ types are aligned.  So the questions is still open in theory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationships between Numpy and C types is listed here (check the "compatible: C ..." sections):
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types

The size-specified types (`int16` etc.) map to C `int`, `long`, `long long` etc. in a platform-specific way. `numpy/ndarrayobject.h` however defines typedefs `npy_int8` and so on.